# How to build a pipeline as shown in blue oceans beta project page

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I am new to Jenkins and looking for ways to automate and visualise workflows. I am able to chain few workflows/jobs together.

[image: my workflow]

I like to learn how to run workflows in parallel, like the picture shown in jenkins blue ocean beta page.

[image: jenkins blue ocean]

Many thanks !

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect what you are really asking as it is extremely vague and misleading currently. That being said, I googled your real question and found these: https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/parallelism-and-distributed-builds-jenkins https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/

Comment: essentially, I like to run job2_a,b,c in parallel and be able to visualise as in picture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building Pipelines with parallel steps is well document in a few guides, I've found these to be the most effective places to find info for me personally:

- [cloudbees.com](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/parallelism-and-distributed-builds-jenkins)
- [jenkins pipeline examples](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples)

I've also answered questions on how to properly set it up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37920722/matrix-configuration-with-jenkins-pipelines/38351561#38351561) *(I know, shameless)*.

---

For the fun it here is the pipeline groovy script to build out the example [obviously missing the actual build commands].

```
node('master') {
    stage('Build') {
        sh "echo Build"
    }
    stage('Test'){
      parallel (
        "JUnit": { 
            sh "echo JUnit"
        },
        "DBUnit": { 
            sh "echo DBUnit"
        },
        "Jasmine": { 
            sh "echo Jasmine"
        },
      )
    }
    stage('Browser Tests'){
      parallel (
        "Firefox": { 
            sh "echo Firefox"
        },
        "Edge": { 
            sh "echo Edge"
        },
        "Safari": { 
            sh "echo Safari"
        },
        "Chrome": { 
            sh "echo Chrome"
        },
      )
    }
    stage('Dev'){
        sh "echo Dev"
    }
    stage('Staging'){
        sh "echo Staging"
    }
    stage('Production'){
        sh "echo Production"
    }
}
```

**UI in action**

[image: demo of blueocean parallel pipeline]

Cheers, and good luck.