# Can't figure out how to create multi-configuration project in Jenkins v2.46.2

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm trying to create a multi-configuration project in Jenkins, but when I click "New Item" I only see two options, freestyle and copy from existing project. I'm using the latest version of Jenkins (v2.46.2), which seems different than previous versions that I've seen on online tutorials.

Comment: For most of the projects you will need to install plugins first, i.e [workflow-paggregator](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) for pipelines

Comment: Probably you are looking for [matrix-project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin)

Comment: also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37920722/matrix-configuration-with-jenkins-pipelines and http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Proper-practice-to-migrate-multi-configuration-matrix-job-to-pipeline-job-td4824062.html if you want to use native pipeline functionality to perform the function multi-configuration matrix jobs used to perform.